# Problemas al ejecutar APP, archivo duplicado xcode swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

tengo el siguiente error al tratar de ejecutar un proyecto, pero si entro y limpio la ruta aun a si no se compone, les muestro las imágenes por si alguien tiene alguna idea o ya le ha pasado.
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estuve revisando y ese tipo de error sale con muchas variantes, en mi caso lo que hice fue primero actualizar el proyecto de swift 4 a swift 4.2 (la versión mas reciente al día de hoy) pero eliminando primero el apartado de CP copy pods resources dentro del Build phases para que pudiera actualizar todo el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez actualizado ejecute pod update para actualizar los pods del proyecto.